# Why is not the rectangle moving across the frame?

Tags: java, swing

I am learning the graphics section and when I have understood what the paintComponent method does, I tried this thing. I tried to draw a rectangle and using a while loop, move it across the frame. But the code does not seem to run. Please note that I am a newbie, and what I did was just a trial.

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class RightFlowLayout extends Panel{

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
         JFrame frame=new JFrame("My");
         Panel panel=new Panel();

         frame.add(panel);
         frame.setSize(600, 600);
         frame.setVisible(true);

    }       

    }


class Panel extends JPanel{
    public int x=20;
    public int y=20;
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        while(true)
        {

            g.fill3DRect(x, y, 50, 50, true);
            x+=5;
            y+=5;
        }
}

}
```

Comment: You are blocking the UI thread like a champ. Nice infinite loop.

Comment: Remove that while loop and see what happens.

Comment: You need to have a global value that defines your X and Y and have the loop that updates your UI take care of it instead. What you have right now is an unscapable piece of code that prevents the screen to update its content.

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM i did not understand what u mean.

Comment: @user1071777.. i did and the block appears. But how can i make it move across the line? And why isn't the loop working here.

Comment: Check my previous comment. You have to understand that execution is sequential, and that includes the code you don't see that makes your square to be drawn on your monitor. What you're doing with that infinite loop (while true) is preventing that code to be executed.

Comment: Google "How to use Swing Timers"

Comment: To fix it you need to create a secondary execution sequence, parallel, a concept called "Thread" in programming. Your secondary thread would update your X, Y values while the original (main, UI) thread continues drawing on the monitor.

Comment: Oh God this is so confusing. Does "Thread" fall under the chapter of "Multithreading"?

Comment: Programming is not easy and has a steep learning curve. If you just want to fix the problem to pass your class just follow the answer below. If you want to learn then yes, any kind of serious user interface uses multithreading.

Comment: Swing Timer is a nice helper class that creates a thread for you and allows you to execute any code you want in it (ActionListener) until you tell it to stop.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of infinite loop try with [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html).

Please have a look at [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Here is the sample code:

```
int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      panel.repaint();
  }
};
Timer timer=new Timer(delay, taskPerformer);
timer.setRepeats(true);
timer.start();
```

Find a [Sample code here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html)

[image]